# How to use grep -c to count ocurrences of various strings in a file?

Tags: shell, grep

i have a bunch files with data from a company and i need to count, let's say, how many people from a certain cities there are. Initially i was doing it manually with

```
grep -c 'Chicago' file.csv
```

But now i have to look for a lot cities and it would be time consuming to do this manually every time. So i did some reaserch and found this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for p in 'Chicago' 'Washington' 'New York'; do
  grep -c '$p' 'file.csv'
done
```

But it doenst work. It keeps giving me 0s as output and im not sure what is wrong. Anyways, basically what i need is for an output with every result (just the values) given by grep in a column so i can copy directly to a spreadsheet. Ex.:

```
132
407
523
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Variables aren't expanded within single quotes.

Comment: Didnt know that, it works now. Thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 1):

You should use **sort + uniq** for that:

```
$ awk '{print $<N>}' file.csv | sort | uniq -c
```

where **N** is the column number of cities (I assume it structured, as it's CSV file).

For example, which shell how often used on my system:

```
$ awk -F:  '{print $7}' /etc/passwd | sort | uniq -c
  1 /bin/bash
  1 /bin/sync
  1 /bin/zsh
  1 /sbin/halt
 41 /sbin/nologin
  1 /sbin/shutdown
$
```

Answer (score 0):

From the title, it sounds like you want to count the number of occurrences of the string rather than the number of lines on which the string appears, but since you accept the `grep -c` answer I'll assume you actually only care about the latter.  Do not use `grep` and read the file multiple times.  Count everything in one pass:

```
awk '/Chicago/ {c++} /Washington/ {w++} /New York/ {n++}
    END { print c; print w; print n }' input-file
```

Note that this will print a blank line instead of "0" for any string that does not appear, so you migt want to initialize.  There are several ways to do that.  I like:

```
 awk '/Chicago/ {c++} /Washington/ {w++} /New York/ {n++}
        END { print c; print w; print n }' c=0 w=0 n=0 input-file
```

Comment: I actually didnt know that grep only counted the lines in which the word appeared but im my case it works fine. Its a .csv file so the city comes in the city column and just appears once per line. Thanks for the tip, this is actually quite simple and helpful. Will keep that in mind next time.